# php mysqli result object cannot immediately be referenced in if statement...?

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, logic, conditional-statements

```
//Execute query and fetch first row  
if ($qry=$db->query("SELECT statement")) {  
  if ($row=$qry->fetch_object()) {

  }  
}


//Same code as above using only one if statement
if ($qry=$db->query("SELECT statement") && $row=$qry->fetch_object()) {

}
```

Why does the second block of code (when run as a replacement to the first) produce the error "Call to function fetch_object on a non-object"?

Comment: Because the PHP compiler decided the one-liner code was non-intuitive for most humans to read

Comment: I had a similar situation and was told that sometimes the program will run faster than it can get the result set.  To avoid this, I had to add a timeout (sleep) to the program to have it pause for a moment to ensure that I got the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because PHP isn't parsing the 2nd statement quite the way you'd expect.

It's reading it as:

```
if ($qry = ($db->query("SELECT statement") && $row = $qry->fetch_object()))
```

Which as you can see, means `$qry` is set before `fetch_object` is called on it.

Try to enclose your statements in `()`:

```
if (($qry=$db->query("SELECT statement")) && ($row=$qry->fetch_object()))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm...!  Seems so obvious now that I look at it!!  Great job - thankyou.